# why g_thread_supported return false in my machine

Tags: c, multithreading, glib

It's Debian `testing- 2.6.38`,

`glib-2.24` ( including gthread)

checking with `pkg-config --cflags/--libs glib-2.0 gthread-2.0`

I tried to write some code using `glib` thread pool, but it's so weird that `g_thread_supported` return `false`.

By the way, `pthread` library(a, so, h) have been installed!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've previously run [g_thread_init](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Threads.html#g-thread-init), which is the function that initializes glib's threading framework.

... from `g_thread_supported`'s documentation ...

> This function returns TRUE if the
>   thread system is initialized, and
>   FALSE if it is not.

Comment: so what is the difference between g_thread_supported and g_thread_get_initialized.

Comment: good question indeed. g_thread_supported must check more stuff than g_thread_get_initialized. I guess.

Comment: `gboolean

g_thread_get_initialized ()

{
  return g_thread_supported ();
}


/* IMPLEMENTATION NOTE:
 *
 * g_thread_supported() is just returns g_threads_got_initialized
 */

/* Checks if thread support is initialized.  Identical to the
 * g_thread_supported macro but provided for language bindings.
 */
gboolean g_thread_get_initialized (void); `


it seems the same between them except language binding, so , this means g_thread_get_initialized is only usable in gtkmm, gtk#, ...